# How print values in dart to browser

Tags: dart, dart-html

The below code is to extract parameter from URL using dart 
I am able to print the values in console but i am not able to get how to display the output in console to browser that is html version. Please help

```dart
import 'dart:core';
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  var q = '?id=abc&id1=cde&id3=asad';

  if(q.contains('?'))  {

   var a = q.replaceFirst("?"," ");

   var c = a.split("&");
   print(c);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the output to the body element or you add an element like a `<div></div>` and insert it inside this element.

To use a 'div' element you should add an element in you `index.html` (or whatever name you have for your HTML page) like

```dart
...
<body>
  <div id='someDiv'></div>
</body>
```

in your Dart code you do it like

```dart
import 'dart:core';
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  var q = '?id=abc&id1=cde&id3=asad';

  if(q.contains('?'))  {

   var a = q.replaceFirst("?"," ");

   var c = a.split("&");
   // querySelector('#someDiv').text = '${c}'; // <= you may need some encoding for special characters like <, >, &, ... 
   var div = querySelector('#someDiv');
   c.forEach((e) => div.append(new DivElement()..text = '${e}'));
 }
```

Comment: this code is showing following error
Breaking on exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 'value'.

Comment: Ok, `print(c)` does a `toString()` automatically, I changed the code behind `).text =`. This should fix it.

Comment: sorry the first answer solved the prob my mistake adding '${c}' in place of c

Thank you

Comment: while printing c value the output is [ id=18278, id1=12312, id3=asad]
how to print them each id in new line without []

Comment: I updated my answer with an example to add each element as a new line.
I haven't tested the code. If you get an error, just add a comment and I'll take a look.
Great, if the answer solves your problem can you please accept it by clicking the checkmark below the up/downvote buttons.

Comment: NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'append'
Receiver: null
Arguments: [Instance of 'DivElement'] (http://127.0.0.1:3030/hi/web/hi.dart:21)
Breaking on exception: The null object does not have a method 'append'.

this is the error i see for new code

Comment: You have the div `<div id='someDiv'></div>` still in your HTML (the id without the '#')?